# Traverse two collections looking for matches, falling back to certain value for those elements that didn't match

Tags: java, java-stream

Say I have two collections of `A { id, foo }` and `B { identifier, bar }`.

Initially I solved this problem using nested `for`-loops, but I did try to solve it (unsuccessful I would say) using the Stream API. Basically I need to traverse both collections looking for matches based on a given condition: `A.id === B.identifier`, in order to create a final map of `A` elements as keys and the values would be the corresponding `A.foo + B.bar` for the matches.

The problem for me in the solution using the Stream API was the second part of the requirements: if some element(s) from `A` did not satisfy the condition, a default value should be assigned (based on a function call)... and I don't know how to plug this while using the Stream API along with the rest of the conditions.

> Notice that the final collection will have as many elements as (initial) `A` — with the modifications.

Is there an efficient way to accomplish this using the Stream API rather than using nested `for`-loops and a couple of `if` conditions?

Comment: Could you share a complete example of the input and output?

Comment: What if collection B has more than one element satisfying the condition `A.id == B.identifier`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you use the temporary collection? If yes, I would suggest to convert `List<B>` into `Map<Identifier, Bar> mapOfB`, so you can much easier and faster find the specified `B.identifier` without need to traverse the B list for each A element.

Then you can simply do something like:

```java
listOfA.stream()
.collect(toMap(a -> a, a -> {
    var bar = mapOfB.get(a.getId());
    if (bar == null) {
        bar = getDefault();
    }
    return a.getFoo() + bar;
}));
```

If you can't create the temporary Map:

```
listOfA.stream()
.collect(toMap(a -> a, a -> {
    var bar = getBarFromBOrDefault(listOfB, a.getId());
    return a.getFoo() + bar;
}))

private Bar getBarFromBOrDefault(List<B> listOfB, Id id) {
    return listOfB.stream()
        .filter(b -> b.getIdentity() == id) // or use .equals() here if it's not a primitive type
        .findFirst()
        .map(B::getBar)
        .orElseGet(() -> getDefault());
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can map each `A` to the list of matching `B`s:

```
List<A> as = ...
List<B> bs = ...

as.stream()
    .map(a -> new Pair<>(a, bs.stream()
                .filter(b -> matches(a, b))
                .toList()))
    .collect(Collectors.toMap(p -> p.fst, p -> p.snd));
```

For this to work you need to declare you own `Pair` type, which is prominently missing from the JDK.

```
record Pair<F, S>(F fst, S snd) {}
```

Note that even there is no nested for loops, there is still nested iteration:  each `A` is mapped to a list of `B`s, which is obtained by traversing all `B`s to find the ones that match.

**Update**

To account for the case where you want to return a default value should there be no matches, you can move the joining to a helper method:

```
private List<B> join(A a, List<B> bs, B defaultB) {
    List<B> matchingBs = bs.stream()
        .filter(b -> matches(a, b))
        .toList();

    return matchingBs.isEmpty()
        ? List.of(defaultB)
        : matchingBs;
}
```

and supply a default value from within the stream processing

```
as.stream()
    .map(a -> new Pair<>(a, join(a, bs, defaultB(a))))
    .collect(Collectors.toMap(p -> p.fst, p -> p.snd));
```

Comment: I was doing something very similar to this...but I can't find where do you account for those values that didn't match the condition, and should be defaulted to another value — coming from a function call.

Comment: @x80486, that bit go lost in my initial reading of you question. I updated the answer to also take this into account.